# How can we make all people peaceful and thoughtful?

Tags: humans, genetics

Could we select peaceful and thoughtful people based on their DNA traits?

I know thoughtful can sometimes bring some sort of violence, but if we could select only the fit, peaceful, and thoughtful humans, would we do that?

---

It would be selected from a "bucket" of sperm and then only those who qualify would be inserted into the egg.

Comment: Isn't procreation selection based on DNA kind of aggressive and arrogant in itself?

Comment: So you seems to be asking two questions. 1) WOULD we select to only have fit, peaceful, and thoughtful humans if we could? 2) Why would or why wouldn't it work? 
The first question has a LOT to consider. We aren't supposed to determine what your characters or groups would do, so much as if it's plausible. 
The second part can be answered more easily. I would assume it's either too complicated for them to do effectively or (if they can do it effectively) why stop with just those traits? Just make perfect humans in general.

Comment: @ChronoD "Just make perfect humans in general" - that's the red area we're getting into, there was an Austrian guy who was crazy for having Perfect Humans, you know his name is something like Arnold or something,oh  I mean Adolf, Gosh! they think alike!

Comment: Dear @Mr.Derpinthoughton . You are asking a community that made great efforts to develop plans to destroy this world, this species, this star system or this universe. There are at least a dozen plans to drug, hypnotise or otherwise manipulate people. We found out how to create armies of perfect soldiers and what to do with them after the war is over. Literally the *last* thing anyone here will do is to judge you just because you want to select humans based on their DNA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it seems to be a philosophical/psychological question. The basic answer is yes, some doctor may feel like playing god and start fiddling with DNA, pulling others in. However, the real events are depending on so many factors that if it wouldn't be off-topic, it would be too broad. I think one has to ask this question to one-self at least once in life, but the answer is as individual as every human. Would you if you could?

Comment: How do you define "peaceful?"  Genetics is a tricky thing.  I've played with Genetic Algorithms myself, algorithms patterned after how genetics works, and I have generally found it to a powerful tool at showing me just how little I truly understood what I wanted.  GA's are the worst sorts of children.  They're the kind that understand what you want, do *exactly* what you say, but find a way to do it in such a way that you just have to shake your head and say "No! No! no! Can I get a do over?"  Make sure you know what "peaceful" *truly* means to you, before invoking genetics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peaceful and thoughtful is not necessarily related to DNA. Your environment and upbringing, your personal beliefs, your philosophical and/or religious position, educational level, your age. These all play a factor in how peaceful and thoughtful you are. We also have yet to identify the gene that produces peacefulness or thoughtfulness. Some scientists May argue that these traits are not genetic in nature. And even if they are genes are clearly just one factor that will determine your peaceful and thoughtful level.

Comment: Even more, i am pretty sure that most people, even if they are peaceful, thoughtful and intelligent, will eventually fight if only thy are threatened badly enough.

Comment: @Burki that's what think would happen

Comment: @Burki do you know the poem ***If a good man goes to war***? I don't really want a thoughtful and intelligent enemy...

Comment: @Brian , a lot of what you say is opinion and speculation.  You may as well be saying everyone is war-like in nature.  There are peaceful chimps, who would rather have sex than engage in aggression.   This is obviously genetics at work.

Comment: @Tim Spriggs You make a lot of assumptions.

Comment: @Tim Spriggs You make a lot of assumptions. First you assume that a peaceful chimp is peaceful because of it genetic code, but that isn't necessarily the case. A lot of factors effect aggression  genes may or may not be one of them. We don't know if genes can directly effect aggression at all .  A lot of things could case a otherwise peaceful chimp to be aggressive such as, limited resources and resources compaction among chimps, PTSD, even the size of the chimp plays a factor  (Smaller chimps will be less aggressive because he is knows that he will lose any fight that they take part in).

Comment: @BM  It's not an assumption.  It's a breed of chimps that are their own species.  Look it up.   And that is DNA-based.

Comment: @BM If there are there own species then by definition they can't be chimps and should we should compare there aggression levels to each other. Also you didn't answer any of my points.

Comment: I Heard something about Epigenes which might be important in this one. There are not only genes which define how you are but also genes which define how you react to your environment so DNA might still be something useful to look at with the goal to make humanity Peace and thought ful. could be that i'm wrong i'm just an it guy no biologist but [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics) i read something like this.